# Square API: Is there a limit / cap on how many times I can poll from the orders API?

Tags: square-connect

I'm currently using the webhook notifications to update my database. Unfortunately there's a 30-40 second delay, so I'm looking into changing my backend so that it polls the orders every x seconds.

Is there a cap on how many times I can do this per day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square's APIs are currently rate limited based on the API you use, how many locations there are, etc. If you are making requests every x seconds, and x is a whole number, you will be well beneath the limit. If you start hitting the rate limit the Square team will be reaching out to see if they can help!

Comment: So is this on a per location basis? What I need is all orders from a specific location every 3 seconds or so. I'd like to store all the orders in my own database. Would you recommend the List Orders endpoint for Connect V1? https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#navsection-orders

Comment: Are you using online store orders, or transactions made in store?

Comment: Transactions made in stores

Comment: you should use v2 transactions list and sorted. polling every three seconds will be totally fine.

Comment: will this respond with the line items + modifiers for each other? (e.g. cappucino, hot, with milk)

Comment: ah, for that you would want to use https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#payments

Comment: Cool. Is this real time? Like if a customer places an in person order, what is the delay before I see that payment returned from that endpoint?

Comment: All of the APIs should be near real time. They use the same services that our 1st party solutions use.

Comment: if i have 23 locations, and I make a request for each location every 3 seconds, does that still keep me under the limit? Or is it requests per merchant?

Comment: It is on the order of 10 requests a second per location, and a higher limit for applications. You are going to be fine.

Comment: Does the Square API support sockets / long polling?

Comment: Not at this time.